# countdown timer for quiz application

Tags: java, android, timer, countdown

I am making a quiz app
I want to implement the countdown timer of 30 secs

Timer need to be constant on top of page actually. I am calling the same page again and again till the round of 15 Questions is over so in that case I want to main the timer count even after the change of activity

```
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
        a++;

        /**
         * validate a Radiobutton has been selected
         */
        if (!checkAnswer())
            return;

        /**
         * check if end of game
         */
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()) {
                db.open();
                String total = currentGame.getRight() + "";
                db.insertOptions(topic1, total, mon);
                db.close();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            a = 0;
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
```

At end of timer I want to fire insert query.In above code I am firing the Insert query at end of quiz
I am not able to understand how should I implement the timer control.

Comment: You can use [Coutdown Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: You dont need to reload the activity on 'onFinish' of countdown timer just start another async task and repopulate the view with another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function on your onCreate and add stuff to your db on onFinish of countdown

```
public void startTicking() {

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timerinterval, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       db.open();
                String total = currentGame.getRight() + "";
                db.insertOptions(topic1, total, mon);
                db.close();
            }
        };
    }
```